# Conversion from string to binary string in Java

Tags: java, binary

I have hexadecimal string of length 80bits like "12345ABCDEF78E9CD741" and need to convert into binary string.

I tried the following code
     String Skey = "12345ABCDEF78E9CD741";
     int i = Integer.parseInt(Skey, 16);
     String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);

But the integer cant hold 80 bits. So how this can be done in java.

Comment: Can you post some code here? Maybe what you have tried.

Comment: that number is way beyond what an integer can hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parse it to a `BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and [convert that to binary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29)

```
BigInteger bigint = new BigInteger("12345ABCDEF78E9CD741", 16);
System.out.println(bigint.toString(2));
```

### Output:

> 10010001101000101101010111100110111101111011110001110100111001101011101000001